# Compare multiple columns for matches in Excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet consisting of three columns, each column indicating the days a certain asset was traded:

```
LS             EX            FA
04.01.2016  04.01.2016  04.01.2016
05.01.2016  05.01.2016  05.01.2016
06.01.2016  06.01.2016  06.01.2016
07.01.2016  07.01.2016  07.01.2016
08.01.2016  08.01.2016  08.01.2016
11.01.2016  11.01.2016  11.01.2016
12.01.2016  12.01.2016  12.01.2016
13.01.2016  13.01.2016  13.01.2016
14.01.2016  14.01.2016  14.01.2016
15.01.2016  15.01.2016  15.01.2016
18.01.2016  19.01.2016  18.01.2016
19.01.2016  20.01.2016  19.01.2016
20.01.2016  21.01.2016  20.01.2016
21.01.2016  22.01.2016  21.01.2016
22.01.2016  25.01.2016  22.01.2016
25.01.2016  26.01.2016  25.01.2016
26.01.2016  27.01.2016  26.01.2016
27.01.2016  28.01.2016  27.01.2016
28.01.2016  29.01.2016  28.01.2016
29.01.2016  01.02.2016  29.01.2016
01.02.2016  02.02.2016  01.02.2016
02.02.2016  03.02.2016  02.02.2016
03.02.2016  04.02.2016  03.02.2016
04.02.2016  05.02.2016  04.02.2016
05.02.2016  08.02.2016  05.02.2016
08.02.2016  09.02.2016  08.02.2016
09.02.2016  10.02.2016  09.02.2016
10.02.2016  11.02.2016  10.02.2016
11.02.2016  12.02.2016  11.02.2016
12.02.2016  16.02.2016  12.02.2016
15.02.2016  17.02.2016  15.02.2016
16.02.2016  18.02.2016  16.02.2016
17.02.2016  19.02.2016  17.02.2016
18.02.2016  22.02.2016  18.02.2016
19.02.2016  23.02.2016  19.02.2016
22.02.2016  24.02.2016  22.02.2016
23.02.2016  25.02.2016  23.02.2016
24.02.2016  26.02.2016  24.02.2016
25.02.2016  29.02.2016  25.02.2016
26.02.2016  01.03.2016  26.02.2016
29.02.2016  02.03.2016  29.02.2016
01.03.2016  03.03.2016  01.03.2016
02.03.2016  04.03.2016  02.03.2016
03.03.2016  07.03.2016  03.03.2016
04.03.2016  08.03.2016  04.03.2016
07.03.2016  09.03.2016  07.03.2016
08.03.2016  10.03.2016  08.03.2016
09.03.2016  11.03.2016  09.03.2016
```

I would like to have one column, which contains only the dates at which all the three assets were traded. 
I'd like to have a fourth column which indicates whether the value in A1, A2 ... An is contained both column B and C (True) or not (False)

The following formula doesn't help, because matching dates are not necessarily in the same row

```
   =IF(AND(A2=B2,A2=C2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Is there something like a vlookup for multiple columns?

Comment: question is not that clear. do you mean have a 4th column that contains either a. a date when the dates in columns 1, 2, and 3 are equal or b. nothing if the first thee dates do not match?  if not, please clarify the question

Comment: Question unclear, also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your edit should have been a comment under the provided answer also.  That way the person who answered will be notified.

Comment: I think I understand the question now, but I wouldn't waste my time in Excel.   I would simply load the spreadsheet into a relational database and perform the proper joins, then re-export back to Excel.  Simple and quick.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2,A2=C2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Apply to column D. You could also return the first cell value instead of TRUE and blank "" instead of FALSE.

Comment: Thanks, but the formula doesn't help, because matching dates are not necessarily in the same row

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in your first output cell:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$2:$C$49/((COUNTIF($A$2:$C$49,$A$2:$C$49)=3)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+1),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]